# Modulus of a large number

Tags: sql, t-sql, modulo

I am trying to calculate the modulus of a very large number (> 38 digits) in T-SQL.

I used to cast my variable as a numeric but now that the number is too large, it is throwing me an error : Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

For example, I would like to know how I should proceed to get the result of this :
17448000012524221015281629272289115277 % 97 (result should be 1 in that case)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What datatype is the large value stored in? I suppose `float`? Or are you just inputting it as a literal?

Comment: It is stored in a varchar(50) before I cast it as a numeric. If needed, I can add the function to the description.

Comment: You can use DECIMAL(P,S) like DECIMAL(30,5). It can support - 10^38 +1 to 10^38 - 1.

Comment: @SudiptaBhattacharyya Decimal can't store the number mentionned in my example. I'm trying to do that for a number that has more than 38 digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute modulus by splitting the long integer into parts based on modulo properties:

> (a + b) mod n = [(a mod n) + (b mod n)] mod n.

and

> ab mod n = [(a mod n)(b mod n)] mod n.

```
17448000012524221015281629272289115277 = 17448000012524221015281629 * 1000000000000 + 272289115277
```

so

```
select ((17448000012524221015281629 % 97)*(1000000000000 % 97) + 272289115277 % 97) % 97 as modulo
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's solution that, when the number is too big, will cut it up to calculate the modulus 97.

The thing is that every 97 by a power of 10 will have 0 as modulus 97

```
    970%97=0
   9700%97=0
  97000%97=0
 970000%97=0
```

So for example
`(` `12345` `)%97`
can be split as
`(` `(123 %97)*100` + `45` `)%97`

> ```
> select *
>
> , case 
>   when len(bignum)>=38
>   then ((cast(left(bignum, len(bignum)-18) as decimal(38,0))%97)
>        * cast(power(1e1,18) as decimal(38,0))
>        + cast(right(bignum, 18) as decimal(38,0)))%97
>   else cast(bignum as decimal(38,0))%97
>   end as mod97
>
> from (values
> ('17448000012524221015281629272289115277'), 
> ('100'), 
> ('97000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001')
> ) q(bignum);
> ```

| bignum | mod97 |
| --- | --- |
| 17448000012524221015281629272289115277 | 77 |
| 100 | 3 |
| 97000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=145b47d526cc70a40405a4cfeb037277)*

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DECLARE @Dividend VARCHAR(100) = '17448000012524221015281629272289115277'
DECLARE @Divisor BIGINT = 97

DECLARE @ChunkSize INT = 10  -- Must be >= 1 and < roughly Log10(bigint max / @Divisor)
DECLARE @Base BIGINT = CONVERT(BIGINT, '1' + REPLICATE('0', @ChunkSize))  -- 10 ^ ChunkSiae
DECLARE @PaddedSize INT = CEILING(LEN(@Dividend) * 1.0 / @ChunkSize) * @ChunkSize 
DECLARE @PaddedValue VARCHAR(100) = RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', @ChunkSize) + @Dividend, @PaddedSize)

DECLARE @Remainder BIGINT = 0
WHILE (LEN(@PaddedValue) > 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PartValue BIGINT = CONVERT(BIGINT, LEFT(@PaddedValue, @ChunkSize))
    SET @Remainder = (@Remainder * @Base + @PartValue) % @Divisor
    SET @PaddedValue = STUFF(@PaddedValue, 1, @ChunkSize, '')
END

SELECT @Remainder
```

If the dividend value might be negative, the sign will need to be extracted and the resulting remainder adjusted.